# Pattern matching with generics

Tags: scala

Given the following class pattern match:

```
clazz match {
  case MyClass => someMethod[MyClass]
}
```

Is it possible to refer to MyClass in a generic way based on what the pattern match came up with?  For example, if I have multiple subclasses of MyClass, can I write a simple pattern match to pass the matched type to `someMethod`:

```
clazz match {
  case m <: MyClass => someMethod[m]
}
```

Comment: It smells like `Manifest`, but as only let us complete an impossible answer without letting space for other options, I have to say "no" to "can I write a simple pattern match to pass the matched type".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately types are not really first class citizens in Scala. This means for example that you cannot do pattern matching on types. A lot of information is lost due to stupid type erasure inherited from the Java platform.

I don't know if there are any improvement requests for this, but this is one of the worst problems in my option, so someone should really come up with such a request.

The truth is you will need to pass around evidence parameters, at best in the form of implicit parameters.

The best I can think of goes in the line of

```
class PayLoad

trait LowPriMaybeCarry {
   implicit def no[C] = new NoCarry[C]
}
object MaybeCarry extends LowPriMaybeCarry {
   implicit def canCarry[C <: PayLoad](c: C) = new Carry[C]
}

sealed trait MaybeCarry[C]
final class NoCarry[C] extends MaybeCarry[C]
final class Carry[C <: PayLoad] extends MaybeCarry[C] {
   type C <: PayLoad
}

class SomeClass[C <: PayLoad]

def test[C]( implicit mc: MaybeCarry[C]) : Option[SomeClass[_]] = mc match {
   case c: Carry[_] => Some(new SomeClass[ c.C ])
   case _ => None
}
```

but still I can't get the implicits to work:

```
test[String]
test[PayLoad]  // ouch, not doin it
test[PayLoad](new Carry[PayLoad])  // sucks
```

So if you want to save yourself serous brain damage, I would forget about the project or look for another language. Maybe Haskell is better here? I'm still hoping that we can eventually match types, but my hopes are pretty low.

Maybe the guys from scalaz have come up with a solution, they pretty much exploited the type system of Scala to the limits.

Comment: Meh. I think that "forget[ting] about the project or look[ing] for another language" is a bit extreme from this one example ^^

Comment: Well, it reflects my frustration with trying to achieve something similar. Cost me a couple of weeks of permanent refactoring, without arriving at a viable solution. So I'm recommending here not to repeat this experience and safe a month of work.

Comment: Your code can't work since `canCarry` requires a non-implicit parameter, hence no wonder it's never applied.
However, a solution exists: I suggest you replace `MaybeCarry` with `OptManifest`, `NoCarry` with `NoManifest` and `Carry` with `Manifest`/`ClassManifest` (the difference I see between the two is mostly in the implementation of `equals`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really clear, because at least in java `clazz` is a typical name for variables of type `java.lang.Class` and variations. I still believe that `clazz` is not an instance of `Class` but of your own class.

In Java and Scala, given an object o: AnyRef you can get access to its class at runtime via `o.getClass: Class[_]`, and for instance create instances of that class through the Reflection API. However, type parameters are passed at compile-time, so you can't pass a type as-is at compile time. Either you use `AnyRef` all over the place as type (which will work, I assume) or you use the reflection API if you have more advanced needs.