# Possible to perform pattern match on a generic value with type conforming result?

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

Is it possible to perform a pattern match whose result conforms to a type parameter of the outer method? E.g. given:

```
trait Key[A] {
  def id: Int
  def unapply(k: Key[_]): Boolean = k.id == id // used for Fail2
  def apply(thunk: => A): A = thunk // used for Fail3
}

trait Ev[A] {
  def pull[A1 <: A](key: Key[A1]): Option[A1]
}

trait Test extends Ev[AnyRef] {
  val key1 = new Key[String] { def id = 1 }
  val key2 = new Key[Symbol] { def id = 2 }
}
```

Is there an implementation of `Test` (its `pull` method) which uses a pattern match on the `key` argument and returns `Option[A1]` for each key checked, without the use of `asInstanceOf`?

Some pathetic tries:

```
class Fails1 extends Test {
  def pull[A1 <: AnyRef](key: Key[A1]): Option[A1] = key match {
    case `key1` => Some("hallo")
    case `key2` => Some('welt)
  }
}

class Fails2 extends Test {
  def pull[A1 <: AnyRef](key: Key[A1]): Option[A1] = key match {
    case key1() => Some("hallo")
    case key2() => Some('welt)
  }
}

class Fails3 extends Test {
  def pull[A1 <: AnyRef](key: Key[A1]): Option[A1] = key match {
    case k @ key1() => Some(k("hallo"))
    case k @ key2() => Some(k('welt))
  }
}
```

None works, obviously... The only solution is to cast:

```
class Ugly extends Test {
  def pull[A1 <: AnyRef](key: Key[A1]): Option[A1] = key match {
    case `key1` => Some("hallo".asInstanceOf[A1])
    case `key2` => Some('welt  .asInstanceOf[A1])
  }
}

val u = new Ugly
u.pull(u.key1)
u.pull(u.key2)
```

Comment: Maybe with some advanced `Manifest` trickery.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365787/pattern-matching-with-generics

Comment: I agree such needs should be assert with Manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed that pattern matching ignores all erased types. However, there is a little implicit trickery that one could employ. The following will preserve the type resolution provided by the match for the return type.

```
abstract class UnErased[A]
implicit case object UnErasedString extends UnErased[String]
implicit case object UnErasedSymbol extends UnErased[Symbol]

class UnErasedTest extends Test {
  def pull[ A1 <: AnyRef ]( key: Key[ A1 ])(implicit unErased: UnErased[A1]): Option[ A1 ] = unErased match {
    case UnErasedString if key1.id == key.id => Some( "hallo" )
    case UnErasedSymbol if key2.id == key.id => Some( 'welt )
    case _ => None
  }
}

val u = new UnErasedTest 
println( u.pull( u.key1 ) )
println( u.pull( u.key2 ) )
```

This is however nearly equivalent to just defining separate sub classes of Key. **I find the following method preferable** however it may not work if existing code is using Key[String] that you can't change to the necessary KeyString (or too much work to change).

```
trait KeyString extends Key[String]
trait KeySymbol extends Key[Symbol]

trait Test extends Ev[ AnyRef ] {
   val key1 = new KeyString { def id = 1 }
   val key2 = new KeySymbol { def id = 2 }
}

class SubTest extends Test {
  def pull[ A1 <: AnyRef ]( key: Key[ A1 ]): Option[ A1 ] = key match {
    case k: KeyString if key1.id == k.id => Some( "hallo" )
    case k: KeySymbol if key2.id == k.id => Some( 'welt )
    case _ => None
  }
}

val s = new SubTest
println( s.pull( s.key1 ) )
println( s.pull( s.key2 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks very much Neil. I previously generated my keys with a method (`key[A]()`), and your approach showed me that I could maybe solve the problem by requiring actual closed types. I have added my approach based on this in a separate answer. I like the matching in your first example, because it uses case objects. I can't get that to work in my extended example, and I don't know why -- maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I provide here an extended example (that shows more of my context) based on the closed types approach of Neil Essy's answer:

```
trait KeyLike { def id: Int }

trait DispatchCompanion {
  private var cnt = 0
  sealed trait Value
  sealed trait Key[V <: Value] extends KeyLike {
    val id = cnt  // automatic incremental ids
    cnt += 1
  }
}

trait Event[V] {
  def apply(): Option[V] // simple imperative invocation for testing
}

class EventImpl[D <: DispatchCompanion, V <: D#Value](
  disp: Dispatch[D], key: D#Key[V]) extends Event[V] {

  def apply(): Option[V] = disp.pull(key)
}

trait Dispatch[D <: DispatchCompanion] {
  // factory method for events
  protected def event[V <: D#Value](key: D#Key[V]): Event[V] =
    new EventImpl[D, V](this, key)

  def pull[V <: D#Value](key: D#Key[V]): Option[V]
}
```

Then the following scenario compiles with not too much clutter:

```
object Test extends DispatchCompanion {
  case class Renamed(before: String, now: String) extends Value
  case class Moved  (before: Int   , now: Int   ) extends Value
  private case object renamedKey extends Key[Renamed]
  private case object movedKey   extends Key[Moved  ]
}
class Test extends Dispatch[Test.type] {
  import Test._

  val renamed = event(renamedKey)
  val moved   = event(movedKey  )

  // some dummy propagation for testing
  protected def pullRenamed: (String, String) = ("doesn't", "matter")
  protected def pullMoved  : (Int   , Int   ) = (3, 4)

  def pull[V <: Value](key: Key[V]): Option[V] = key match {
    case _: renamedKey.type => val p = pullRenamed; Some(Renamed(p._1, p._2))
    case _: movedKey.type   => val p = pullMoved;   Some(Moved(  p._1, p._2))
  }
}
```

...and yields the desired results:

```
val t = new Test
t.renamed()
t.moved()
```

Now the only thing I don't get and I find ugly is that my cases must be of the form

```
case _: keyCaseObject.type =>
```

and cannot be

```
case keyCaseObject =>
```

which I would very much prefer. Any ideas where this limitation comes from?